# Javafx web client with a server

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

I have to make a final project (Software Engineering) which should be on web (I chose javafx over HTML5). The project's purpose is to learn people typing blindly. The user gets a sentence and he should rewrite it. The application should save all the information of users so that is why I need a server.

I have got some questions:

1. Can I use simple java socket server with javafx?
2. If the answer is yes, are there web hosting services that support simple socket server? I heard something about tomcat or something like this. If the answer is no, what other choices do I have?
3. What is the best plugin for eclipse to work with javafx? I mean, I need a designer.
4. Another thing that I need from the server is to send sound files to the client, which type of java server allows it?

Comment: Flagges as too broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your overall design is feasible.  Start designing and developing it and create new, very specific, targeted questions when you need to (one question per question).  When you create a new question it may be a good idea to include minimal executable source code which replicates just the issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I use simple java socket server with javafx?

Yes. It's a Java application, after all, and you can open a socket (client or server).

> 2. If the answer is yes, are there web hosting services that support simple socket server? I heard something about tomcat or something like this. If the answer is no, what other choices do I have?

You should not focus on this. Instead, try to create a set of (REST) services. Your application in the server side (Jetty, Tomcat or whatever) will be the producer and your Java FX application will be a consumer of these services.

> 3. What is the best plugin for eclipse to work with javafx? I mean, I need a designer.

This is off topic because it falls into personal preference. I don't know about such a designer. And IMO I prefer to design in my head and just write the code I come up with that.

> 4. Another thing that I need from the server is to send sound files to the client, which type of java server allows it?

A sound file is a file, after all, and a file is just a `byte[]` that will be sent through the net. Learn how to handle this when creating/consuming your services.